# Automatically grading submissions in private git repositories

Tags: github, repository

We have an automatic homework grading script that work as follows:

- The students upload their solutions to their GitHub repositories, and submit URLs to their repositories.
- Our script reads the URLs, automatically clones each repository, and runs the tests on the files.

It works well when the students' repositories are public, but now we would like to allow the students to submit private repositories too. What should the students do in order to allow our grading script to read their private repositories?

One option is that we open a GitHub account for the script, and have the students add this account as "collaborator" to the repository they submit. But, this would require us to approve each such addition, which might take a long time (there are almost 300 students).

Is there another, automated way to do this?

Comment: Is [GitHub Classroom](https://classroom.github.com/) not an option?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I tried, but from what I saw, it lets the students change the test files in their repositories. So the students can just write tests that give them a 100. Maybe I did not understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to build a [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/about-apps) that students could give permissions to read their private repos. They could then tag commits for the app to review.